# How can i remove auto="dir" for p-tags in Gitlab?

Tags: html, css, image, gitlab, markdown

I want to center an image in my readme.md (for my extension) in my Gitlabs Repository.

FYI: I use html-code, because i want another width, i found something for the width with markdown, but that doesn't work.

## Things i found on stackoverflow and tried in readme.md:

**1. style="text-align:center;"**

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="..." alt="..." width="250">
</p>
```

The result html-code: `<p dir="auto">`

(I post only this line, because here is the failure.)

**2. class="text-center"**

```
<p class="text-center">
  <img src="..." alt="..." width="250">
</p>
```

The result html-code: `<p dir="auto">`

**3. align="middle"**

```
<p align="middle">
  <img src="..." alt="..." width="250">
</p>
```

The result html-code: `<p align="middle" dir="auto">`

**4. Only IMG-Tag (without P-Tags)**

Point 1 to 3 i also tried inside the image-tag and without a wrapping p-tag.

But the result html-code **also makes a p-wrap around the image-tag**: `<p dir="auto">`

---

### Near a solution ?

I find out if i take **the 3.rd try** and **remove the `dir="auto"` with the Development-Tools** the **centering works**.

### More investigation

On GitHub i have seen there aren't automatic `dir="auto"` param in p tags and nowhere.

But on GitLabs it is like this.

### So my questions are:

## How can i remove `auto="dir"` for `p-tags` in Gitlab?

**OR**

## Where can i change the css in my Gitlab for `dir="auto"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I found a solution:

If you make a `div-wrap` around the `p-wrap` it prevents the `dir="auto"` problem.

So my sourcecode now looks like this:

#### Div Wrap - P Center and Image

```
<div>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="/uploads/12676084bd8b8b0c6f38df97b21d5d8d/MyImage.svg" width="250">
    </p>
</div>
```

#### Div Wrap - P Center - Link and Image

```
<div>
    <p align="center">
        <a href="http://E.ntwickler.de" title="TEST TITLE" target="_blank">
            <img src="/uploads/12676084bd8b8b0c6f38df97b21d5d8d/MyImage.svg" width="250">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

### Here is the code of Gitlab (for better reading i make some linebrakes)

#### Div Wrap - P Center and Image

```
<div>
    <p align="center">
        <a class="no-attachment-icon" href="http://MYGITLABSERVER.de/Monti/rmcomment/uploads/12676084bd8b8b0c6f38df97b21d5d8d/MyImage.svg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="http://MYGITLABSERVER.de/Monti/rmcomment/uploads/12676084bd8b8b0c6f38df97b21d5d8d/MyImage.svg" width="250" class="js-lazy-loaded">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

#### Div Wrap - P Center - Link and Image

```
<div>
    <p align="center">
        <a href="http://MYLINKURL" title="TEST TITLE" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener">
            <img src="http://MYGITLABSERVER.de/Monti/rmcomment/uploads/12676084bd8b8b0c6f38df97b21d5d8d/MyImage.svg" width="250" class="js-lazy-loaded">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now the sourcecode of Gitlab looks fine and i did not have to hack some Gitlab-Css-Files or make some other DOM manipulation.